# keywords missing after install robotframework-autoitlibrary

Tags: robotframework

I followed the steps below to install robotframework-autoitlibrary

```
1.Open cmd in "Run as administrator" mode
2.run the command pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary
3.Now clone the autoit library source code: nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary.
4.in the root directory run the below command: python setup.py install using cmd in admin mode
```

but after it installed many keyword are missing , only few keywords from autoit library that I can use are below, how can i get full keywords library available ?
[image]